# Read embedded MSWord file from excel uand save it on drive using Java

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, apache-poi

I have excel file with two Ms Word file embedded in it.
I am using Apache POI to read Embedded object from excel file in java.
Problem is when I read embedded file and save it on Disk and opened saved file in Ms Word, MS Word couldn't read its format.
If  opened from excel file directly it opened and Ms Word read it properly.
Anyone help me.
[Code]

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:/Book2.xls");
        NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(file);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot(), true);
        for (HSSFObjectData obj : wb.getAllEmbeddedObjects()) {
            String oleName = obj.getOLE2ClassName();
            DirectoryNode dn = (DirectoryNode)obj.getDirectory();
            Iterator<Entry> ab = dn.getEntries();
            if(oleName.contains("Document")){
                HWPFDocument embeddedWordDocument = new HWPFDocument(dn);
              String docTitle = embeddedWordDocument.getSummaryInformation().getTitle();
                InputStream is ;
                Entry entry = ab.next();
                is = dn.createDocumentInputStream(entry);

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:/"+docTitle+".doc");
                System.out.println(is.available());
                 System.out.println(((DocumentEntry)entry).getSize());
                IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }
        fs.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can Apache POI read the file you've saved out? i.e. is it a problem with the saving process, or with POI not including something that Word expects?

Comment: @gagravarr    can you tell me how to do that.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is grab the `tika-app` jar from Apache Tika, and use the `-z` flag - that'll handle calling POI to do the extraction